# Derive Q-dynamics of $\ln S_t$ having multiplicative error structure

Tags: asset-pricing, continuous-time

From *Kwon, T. Y. (2012). Three essays on credit risk models and their bayesian estimation (Doctoral dissertation)*:

Assume the following log equity price model:
 $$\ln S_t = g_S(V_t,t,\Theta_V) + Z_T$$

where $g_S$ is a function of $V_t$ (value of firm's assets), $t$ (time) and $\Theta_V$ (parameters governing the asset dynamics);
and $Z_t$ - market noise.

We also model $V_t$ and $Z_t$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
     dV_t &= \mu V_t dt + \sigma_V d W_t^{\mathbb{P}V}\\
     dZ_t &= -\theta_Z Z_t dt + \sigma_Z dW_t^{\mathbb{P}Z}
\end{align}
$$

By applying Itô's lemma, we can derive the $\mathbb P$ dynamics of $\ln S_t$:

$$
\begin{align}
    d \ln S_t &= d g_S + d Z_t \\
              &= \frac{\partial g_S}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial g_S}{\partial V} dV + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g_S}{\partial V^2} (dV)^2 -\theta_Z Z_t dt + \sigma_Z d W_t^{\mathbb{P}Z}\\
              &= \left(\frac{\partial g_S}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial g_S}{\partial V} \mu V_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g_S}{\partial V^2} \sigma_V^2 V_t^2 -\theta_Z \left(\ln S_t- g_S\right) \right) dt + \\
              &\qquad+ \frac{\partial g_S}{\partial V}\sigma_V V_t d W_t^{\mathbb{P}V} + \sigma_Z d W_t^{\mathbb{P}Z}
\end{align}
$$

> **Task**:  Derive the $\mathbb{Q}$ dynamics of $\ln S_t$.

The text of the thesis then says:

> Since the discounted $S_t$ is a martingale under $\mathbb Q$ and its
>   volatility term remains unchanged under both measures $\mathbb P$ and
>   $\mathbb Q$, we now conclude that under $\mathbb Q$, $S_t$ follows:
>
> $$ \begin{align}
>      d \ln S_t &= \left(r - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial g_S}{\partial V} \sigma_V V_t\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_Z^2 \right) dt +\\
>                &\qquad+ \frac{\partial g_S}{\partial V}\sigma_V V_t d W_t^{\mathbb{Q}V} + \sigma_Z d W_t^{\mathbb{Q}Z} \end{align} $$

It is not entirely clear for me why this result follows from that. I would like to see the maths.